# 0xcdcdcdcd while using this->

Tags: c++, object

Hi im doing little project tomy school and keep getting weird for me error.

While calling one of methods in my object this pointer is set to **0xcdcdcdcd**. i googled it and found some info about erasing memory or destroing objects before calling, but i make sure no destructors are called before.

World.h

```
class Organism;
class Human;

class World
{
private:
   vector <Organism*> organisms;

   vector <Organism*> organismsToAdd;

   vector <string> logs;

   int turn_;

   void initializeWorld();

   void drawInterface();

   void drawInfo();
   void drawOrganisms();
   void nextTurn();
   bool isPositionTaken(int x, int y);
   Organism* getOrganism(int x, int y);
   void queueOrganismToAdd(Organism* newOrganism);
   void addQueuedOrganisms();
   void generateStartOrganisms();
   bool isPlayerAlive();
public:
   void executeMove(Organism* moving, int toX, int toY);  //here's the problem
   bool isPositionValid(int x, int y);
   World(int x, int y);
   struct
   {
       int x_, y_;
   } worldSize;
   void startGame();
   ~World();
 };
```

executeMove

```
void World::executeMove(Organism* moving, int toX, int toY)
{
   cout << moving->getSign();
   getch();
   if (!isPositionTaken(toX, toY))  //  <- here it brake
   {
       moving->setPosition(toX, toY);
   }
   else if (moving->getSign() == getOrganism(toX, toY)->getSign())
   {
    //multiply
    //make log
   }
   else {
      if (!moving->specialCollision((getOrganism(toX, toY)))) return;
      if (!getOrganism(toX, toY)->specialCollision(moving)) return;
      if (moving->getPower() >= getOrganism(toX, toY)->getPower())
      {
        //log
        //delete losser
       }
      else
      {
        //log
        //delete losser
       }
    moving->setPosition(toX, toY);
   }
}
```

isPositioinTaken

```
bool World::isPositionTaken(int x, int y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->organisms.size(); ++i)  // here this is set to 0xcdcdcdcd
    {
        if (organisms[i]->getPositionX() == x && organisms[i]->getPositionY() == y) return true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

Method isPositionTaken is worlking well in other parts of project so im totally lost if finding whats wrong, i aprreciate any help

Comment: Is the pointer always set to that specific value on every run of the program? Also, where are you calling `WorldInstance->executeMove()`? If the pointer is malformed it's probably going to be in that code not the class itself...

Comment: 0xcdcdcdcd usually means some memory is not initialized, be we can't see enough of the program to tell you where that is.

Comment: whith pointer? Class World holds a vector of Organisms and this function checks if some place is free, this->organisms points to elemet of this class

Comment: im calling it in one of subclass of Organisms like wolf or sth

Comment: There is no universal answer. Your code has a bug somewhere. You have to find it. There are static analysis tools like valgrind or purify, that can often find where things go off the rails. Otherwise, my usual approach is to start stubbing out and bypassing chunks of my code, until the symptoms of the bug go away, so the bug is PROBABLY somewhere in the last chunk that I stubbed out. C++ debugging is hard.

Comment: Could set a break on every mention of the variable in question in a debugger and just see where it goes wrong.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `organisms` member has a default constructor, the only way to see this behavior at the line you indicated is if the call to executeMove() was using a pointer which was uninitialized.

Something like:

```
World *ptr; // not initialized on stack
    ...
ptr->executeMove();
```

Or this method was called from another method with the same problem.

Comment: I would add that he should check if his constructor is being called, i.e. `World(int x, int y);`. He should initialise his world object either on the stack with `World my_world(0, 0);` or on the heap if there is a good reason to do so with `World *my_world = new World(0, 0)`. He could also be creating the object on the stack already and calling it later via pointer to the object that had gone out of scope (but he does claim no destructor is called).